# How to configure the editor's line height in NetBeans 6.9.1?

Tags: windows, text-editors, netbeans

Is there a way to change the editor's line height in Netbeans without resorting to redundant newlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on [gulbandr's](https://superuser.com/users/44200/gulbrandr) [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/207393/how-to-configure-the-editors-line-height-in-netbeans-6-9-1/207421#207421):

For Netbeans 6.8 and above on Windows, change some arbitrary setting under "Tools/Options/Editor" to trigger the creation of a configuration file. It gets created at

```
%USERPROFILE%\.netbeans\6.8\config\Editors\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

Then add the following lines into the `<editor-preferences>` element:

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">
    <value><![CDATA[1.5]]></value>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 5):

For netbeans 7.2.x on Windows 7, the location is slightly different (but can be found without too much digging).

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Editors\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

And then, as others have mentioned, above, add the following at the end (but before the `</editor-preferences>` closing tag:

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">
    <value><![CDATA[1.5]]></value>
</entry>
```

Note that here, the actual line-spacing value is `1.5` which means 1.5 x the default line-spacing, i.e.: 150%.

Answer (score 2):

The file *org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml* can be found in `{install_dir}\ide\config\Modules`. If it’s not there, change any editor settings in NetBeans IDE, and it’ll create it.

Open this file in your favourite text editor, and add the following code right before the last line (right before the `</editor-preferences>` tag):

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">
    <value><![CDATA[0.7]]></value>
</entry>
```

Then restart NetBeans.

[source](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/change-line-height-in-netbeans/)

Comment: For Netbeans 6.9.1 that's not entirely accurate.

Comment: Indeed. You answer seems better.

Comment: [gulbandr's](http://superuser.com/users/44200/gulbrandr) [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/207393/how-to-configure-the-editors-line-height-in-netbeans-6-9-1/207421#207421) worked as expected in Netbeans 7.1.1 in Mac OSX Lion.

Comment: If on Mountain Lion for NetBeans >= 7.2.1 you fail find the file _org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml_ in the suggested directory, have a look in **~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2.1/config/Editors/Preferences**

Answer (score 1):

Within the `Fonts & Colors` tab, try adjusting the `Whitespace` field to 20~25px.

Comment: Why does this work better than the accepted answer from Saul?